# VB.NET Program Crashes with no errors

Tags: .net, vb.net, resources, crash

I am using VB.NET Framework 3.5 . I have a very complicated program with over 40 forms and 100s of lines of coding. Earlier today, this program worked perfectly. I decided to change the Assembly Name from APA to Salamander. I do not get any errors and things seem to be going fine. Upon the next debug, the splash screen loads fine. (I am using a timer to proceed to the main form, not the inbuilt splash screen setting as I found it to be more reliable). However, when the main form loads, none of the pictures (resources) load and it exits itself immediately yet no errors appear at all. I think it might be to do with the .resources file but I really don't know. As I only started Visual Basic less than two months ago I'm not sure what all the files other than .vb files actually are.

I really don't want to have to completely rebuild the program as my release date is in five days and as I am still at school I don't have time  to complete it on top of homework. I have tried changing the assembly name back to APA again but it still does not work. I am completely stumped.

In case it helps, you can download the project file (please do not say it is your own and publish it on the net) here - http://

Comment: Sorry [Gamefront](http://bit.ly/apaerror1) and [MediaFire](http://bit.ly/apaerror2). Even though it comes up with a warning I did not put a virus in this because I genuinely need this question to be answered :/

Comment: Debug + Exceptions, check the Thrown boxes.

Comment: --check your link. it just shows up as "`http://`" (for me at least)

Answer (score 1):

Set a breakpoint on line 1 of your code by putting the cursor on line 1 and pressing F9.  Proceed to debug your program by pressing F5.  Now you can step through each line of your program by pressing F10 and you will find the line that is causing your program to crash.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a Do Loop being run in your program which is causing this program add "Application.DoEvents()" as the first line in the loop to instruct the program to keep running which doesn't stop the images or any other resources from loading

Thanks

Comment: Even if the program is using a loop (and it doesn't sound like that is his issue), using DoEvents() is almost always a bad idea.